# UIAlertController customized build on Storyboard not works correctely

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uialertcontroller

I need a `UIAlertController` with a Title, Description and a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. I have a set of objects that need be downloaded on webservice, to show the feedback to user I create a `UIAlertController` and modify the description conforms downloads are finished and started, in serie. So, when I show my customized `UIAlertController` that view take all screen of my app! I want just show the small box that I created on storyboard, like a popup, to informs user to progress of download.

I tried make this:

Alerta.swift

```
class Alerta: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var indicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDesc: UILabel!

    var titulo: String?
    var descricao: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.lblTitle.text = titulo
        self.lblDesc.text = descricao
        indicatorView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        indicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

To test I did write a little code with delay.

ViewControllerMain.swift

```
let customAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "waitView") as! Alerta
    customAlert.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    customAlert.definesPresentationContext = true
    customAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    customAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve

    customAlert.titulo = "Título"
    customAlert.descricao = "Descrição 1"
    self.present(customAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(2000)) {
        customAlert.lblDesc.text = "Descricao 2"
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(4000)) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And this is my storyboard
[image]

And the results (bad):

[image]

Comment: You could try customizing the UIAlertController itself. Presenting another view controller won't serve the purpose and if you set the background color to clear color then also you won't be able to see the presenting view controller form the presented view controller.

Comment: I change my question

Comment: It is not nice to change your question so radically (and it is now complete unclear what the question _is_). However, in a sense, my answer still applies; it is a lot simpler to change the message dynamically if you use one of the solutions I proposed, because they both give you complete control over the contents of the dialog, whereas UIAlertController does not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think that was wrong. Thank you for your help, but I'am newest in the iOS development, and I don't understand some things. You can explain how I customize a UIAlertController with UIActivityIndicatorView ?

Comment: "You can explain how I customize a UIAlertController with UIActivityIndicatorView" You can't. That's why my answer is still my answer. Did you download the example project? Did you run it? You can easily see that it looks like an alert but it's _your_ alert so you are free to put an activity indicator into it.

Comment: I’ve rolled this back to the first revision. Please don’t radically alter answered questions; a question with answers forms a whole we’d like to keep fitting together for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you're describing by a simple Over Current Context presentation. The current context is the presenting view controller — plus, your storyboard main view is much bigger than the view you want, and the runtime has no way to magically guess that the only relevant part of the view is the shaded part.

If you really want this to be a presented view controller, you would need to use a Custom presentation and supply your own presentation controller that will set the frame of the presented view.

However, I would suggest that you simply create and show a *view* — there is no need for a full-fledged presented view controller in this simple scenario.

Comment: For custom presentation, downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7. But, as I say, you don't need that; just show a view.

Comment: In the sample, how .xib is related with CustomAlertViewController.swift and the CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift is really necessary?

Comment: I don't know make that you says